# use a virtual file system with Lucene.NET

Tags: .net, lucene, lucene.net, virtualfilesystem

Is there a way to use a virtual filesystem with Lucene.NET? Based on my (moderate) experience with Lucene, I suspect the answer here is no; but just in case (...) barring that:

Or is there an existing Contrib module or add-on for Lucene.NET that adds VFS support?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Also, what do you intend to solve with this?

Comment: @Mauricio Lucene seems to require references to objects like System.IO.Directory to function. I am in an environment where I don't have direct access to the physical disk space, I need to be able to hand it a virtualized file system provider that routes to an arbitrary store.

Comment: @Mauricio for a very crude example, I should be able to hand it a Stream (or a StreamProvider) instead of a Directory that it writes to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by implementing `Lucene.Net.Store.Directory`. The xmldoc for this abstract class is very didactic:

> A Directory is a flat list of files.  Files may be written once, when
> they are created.  Once a file is created it may only be opened for
> read, or deleted.  Random access is permitted both when reading and
> writing.
>
> Java's i/o APIs not used directly, but rather all i/o is through this
> API.  This permits things such as:
>
> - implementation of RAM-based indices;
> - implementation indices stored in a database, via JDBC;
> - implementation of an index as a single file;
>
> Directory locking is implemented by an instance of LockFactory, and
> can be changed for each Directory instance using setLockFactory.

[Here's an example of implementing a custom Directory to support Azure](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Azure-Library-for-83562538).

Comment: Aha - I didn't dig deeply into that part of it. Great implementation example!